Suggest Hostname в Яндекс OAuth
При регистрации приложения в Яндекс, для использования OAuth, просит Suggest Hostname. Что это и что нужно туда вставить? OAuth хочу использовать для телеграм бота.
Пробовал вставлять ссылки на сам телеграм бот, не пишет не валидная ссылка (на скриншоте).

